# Statistical Test for multinomial distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multinomial-distribution

Suppose there is a multinomial distribution $X \sim Mul(p_1, ..., p_k)$ and I have $n$ samples, where $n_i$ samples gives the first category, .... Then, the sample mean are $\hat p_1 = \frac {n_1}n, \dots, \hat p_k = \frac {n_k}n$. I would like to have a statistical test on the following hypothesises:
$$
H_0: p_1=\dots=p_{k-1}, \quad H_1:\text{any pair of } \{p_i\}_{i=1}^{k-1} \text{ is distinct}
$$

I have no idea what I should do in the next step. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: I posted something like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/576759/247274) as an answer until I realized that I wasn’t as sure of myself as I wanted to be. If the answer is that my method makes sense, that is a viable approach.